# Shellcoding emacs to make it run vim

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, portable-executable, shellcode, x64dbg

I am attempting to modify the x64 assembly code of emacs to make it run vim in background using a shellcode. I normally do this on x32 with `pushad` and `pushfd` but I am blocked in x64. I will give more context.

The normal assembly of emacs is as follows:

```
00007FF631D014B0 | 48:83EC 28               | sub rsp,28                              |
00007FF631D014B4 | 48:8B05 A5300000         | mov rax,qword ptr ds:[7FF631D04560]     | rax:EntryPoint
00007FF631D014BB | C700 01000000            | mov dword ptr ds:[rax],1                | rax:EntryPoint
00007FF631D014C1 | E8 BAFCFFFF              | call runemacs.7FF631D01180              |
00007FF631D014C6 | 90                       | nop                                     |
00007FF631D014C7 | 90                       | nop                                     |
00007FF631D014C8 | 48:83C4 28               | add rsp,28                              |
00007FF631D014CC | C3                       | ret                                     |
00007FF631D014CD | 0F1F00                   | nop dword ptr ds:[rax],eax              |
00007FF631D014D0 | 48:83EC 28               | sub rsp,28                              |
00007FF631D014D4 | 48:8B05 85300000         | mov rax,qword ptr ds:[7FF631D04560]     | 
.........
```

At the end there is a code cave with a lot of zeros. I want to put my shellcode there, make the binary run vim then go back and run emacs.
To do that, I modify the above as follow:

```
00007FF6D23114B0 | E9 0C180000              | jmp runemacs_vim3.7FF6D2312CC1          | (make it jump to the code cave)
00007FF6D23114B5 | 8B05 A5300000            | mov eax,dword ptr ds:[7FF6D2314560]     | (rax changed to eax by my debugger _x64dbg)
00007FF6D23114BB | C700 01000000            | mov dword ptr ds:[rax],1                | rax:EntryPoint
00007FF6D23114C1 | E8 BAFCFFFF              | call runemacs_vim3.7FF6D2311180         |
00007FF6D23114C6 | 90                       | nop                                     |
00007FF6D23114C7 | 90                       | nop                                     |
00007FF6D23114C8 | 48:83C4 28               | add rsp,28                              |
00007FF6D23114CC | C3                       | ret                                     |
00007FF6D23114CD | 0F1F00                   | nop dword ptr ds:[rax],eax              |
00007FF6D23114D0 | 48:83EC 28               | sub rsp,28                              |
00007FF6D23114D4 | 48:8B05 85300000         | mov rax,qword ptr ds:[7FF6D2314560]     | rax:EntryPoint
00007FF6D23114DB | C700 00000000            | mov dword ptr ds:[rax],0                | rax:EntryPoint
00007FF6D23114E1 | E8 9AFCFFFF              | call runemacs_vim3.7FF6D2311180         |
```

Then down at `runemacs_vim3.7FF6D2312CC1`  at the code cave:

```
00007FF69D3D2CC1 | 9C                       | pushfq                                  |
00007FF69D3D2CC2 | 50                       | push rax                                | rax:EntryPoint
00007FF69D3D2CC3 | 51                       | push rcx                                |
00007FF69D3D2CC4 | 52                       | push rdx                                | rdx:EntryPoint
00007FF69D3D2CC5 | 53                       | push rbx                                |
00007FF69D3D2CC6 | 54                       | push rbp                                |
00007FF69D3D2CC7 | 55                       | push rsi                                |
00007FF69D3D2CC8 | 56                       | push rdi                                |


MY SHELLCODE THAT RUNS VIM


00007FF69D3D2DCD | EB 0F                    | jmp runemacs_vim2.7FF69D3D2DDE          | ---- (to avoid the shellcode exiting the program)
00007FF69D3D2DCF | 59                       | pop rcx                                 |    |
00007FF69D3D2DD0 | 41:89DA                  | mov r10d,ebx                            |    |
00007FF69D3D2DD3 | FFD5                     | call rbp                                |    |
00007FF69D3D2DD5 | 76 69                    | jbe runemacs_vim2.7FF69D3D2E40          |    |
00007FF69D3D2DD7 | 6D                       | insd                                    |    |
00007FF69D3D2DD8 | 2E65:78 65               | js runemacs_vim2.7FF69D3D2E41           |    |
00007FF69D3D2DDC | 0000                     | add byte ptr ds:[rax],al                |    |  rax:EntryPoint
00007FF69D3D2DDE | 5F                       | pop rdi                                 | <---
00007FF69D3D2DDF | 5E                       | pop rsi                                 |
00007FF69D3D2DE0 | 5D                       | pop rbp                                 |
00007FF69D3D2DE1 | 5C                       | nop                                     |  ( a small mistake because I used to push rsp)
00007FF69D3D2DE2 | 5B                       | pop rbx                                 |
00007FF69D3D2DE3 | 5A                       | pop rdx                                 | rdx:EntryPoint
00007FF69D3D2DE4 | 59                       | pop rcx                                 |
00007FF69D3D2DE5 | 58                       | pop rax                                 | rax:EntryPoint
00007FF69D3D2DE6 | 9D                       | popfq                                   |
00007FF69D3D2DE7 | 48:83EC 28               | sub rsp,28                              |
00007FF69D3D2DEB | E9 C4E6FFFF              | jmp runemacs_vim2.7FF69D3D14B4          |
00007FF69D3D2DF0 | 0000                     | add byte ptr ds:[rax],al                | rax:EntryPoint
00007FF69D3D2DF2 | 0000                     | add byte ptr ds:[rax],al                | rax:EntryPoint
```

When I run it, vim runs normally but emacs don't. The debugger shows that `00007FF69D3D14B5 | 8B05 A5300000            | mov eax,dword ptr ds:[7FF69D3D4560]     |` is giving an access violation. Why did my debbugger change rax to eax ? Am I missing something when simulating the `pushad` in x64 by pushing and poping all the registers ?

Comment: You have overwritten a 4 byte instruction with a 5 byte one thereby clobbering the first byte of the next instruction which was the 48 prefix that turned `eax` into `rax`. Also, you jump back to `B4` which is now not the start of an instruction, hence the fault (it decodes as `add  [rbx+0x30000005], cl`).